# Query which was working fine earlier now takes more time to run in Android device after it got updated to Android 14

Tags: sqlite, android-14

One of the queries in my application which was working fine in earlier versions of android (below android 14) is now taking more time (8 to 10 minutes) to run after the device got updated to Android 14.  I also tried this scenario in emulator (Android 14) and also facing same issue.
Has anyone faced similar issue like this?

Note : Our application uses SQLite Database not Room.

```
Select 
  DISTINCT SRD.A, 
  SRD.B, 
  PM.C, 
  P.PID as D, 
  P.PName as E, 
  IFNULL(SRD.Target, 0) as F, 
  CASE WHEN (SRT.Compliant IS NULL) THEN SRD.Actual ELSE SRT.Actual END as G, 
  CASE WHEN (
    SRD.RemainingDays IS NULL 
    or SRD.RemainingDays = ''
  ) THEN 10000 ELSE CASE WHEN (SRD.RemainingDays < 0) THEN 100000 ELSE SRD.RemainingDays END END as H, 
  SRD.SOP as I, 
  SRD.TAT as J, 
  SRD.Model as K, 
  CASE WHEN (SRT.Compliant IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as L, 
  CASE WHEN (
    SRD.SOP IS NULL 
    OR SRD.SOP = ''
  ) THEN 0 ELSE SRD.SOP END as TaskSop 
From 
  Table1 SRD 
  INNER JOIN Table2 PM ON PM.PId = SRD.ProductId 
  AND PM.Plid = 54321 
  INNER JOIN Table2 P ON PM.ParentHierarchy LIKE '%/' || P.PId || '/%' 
  AND P.PLid = 654321 
  LEFT JOIN Table3 SRT ON SRT.MappingId = SRD.ProductId 
  AND SRT.MenuCode = 'MENU_1' 
  AND SRT.RetailerId = 123456 
  AND SRT.TaskId = SRD.TaskId 
  LEFT JOIN Table4 IM ON IM.TaskId = SRD.TaskId 
  and IM.MenuCode = 'MENU_1' 
  AND IM.RetailerId = 123456 
  AND IM.Status != 'STATUS' 
WHERE 
  SRD.Model = 'MODELNAME' 
  and SRD.RetailerId = 123456 
  and PM.PID IN (
    Select 
      DISTINCT PGM.PID 
    From 
      Table5 PCM 
      INNER JOIN Table6 PTM ON PTM.GroupId = PCM.GroupId 
      AND PTM.TaggingTypelovID = (
        SELECT 
          ListId 
        FROM 
          Table7 
        WHERE 
          ListCode = 'MENU_1' 
          AND ListType = 'LISTTYPE'
      ) 
      AND (
        PCM.CriteriaType = 'CRITERIATYPE' 
        and PCM.CriteriaId IN(123, 1234) 
        OR (
          PCM.criteriatype = 'CRITERIATYPE1' 
          and PCM.criteriaid = 4321
        )
      ) 
      INNER JOIN Table8 PGM ON PGM.GroupId = PTM.GroupId
```